# SQL group by Query does not work

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

I have two queries, that are very similar, one works and the other keeps giving me an error about an item not being contained in the group by clause, even though it is. The two queries are "almost" identical, except for 1 field. I have compared the two up and down and cannot figure out why the second does not work

this one works just fine:

```
SELECT o.Org+'-'+o.OrgSUB as 'orgsub',o.PSO,count(g.id) as caseNo,
 grouping(o.Org+'-'+o.OrgSUB ) AS ORGSUBTOTAL, grouping(o.PSO) AS PSOTOTAL 
 from g,o
        where  g.ORG+'-'+g.ORGSUB = o.ORG+'-'+o.ORGSUB and o.active='y' and 
  GROUP BY o.Org+'-'+o.OrgSUB ,o.PSO 
  WITH ROLLUP ORDER BY o.Org+'-'+o.OrgSUB desc, o.PSO desc, ORGSUBTOTAL , PSOTOTAL
```

now if i replace PSO and ORG (so that the results show by ORG and then by combination of org and orgsub together, i get the following error:

Column 'o.orgsub' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
 SELECT o.Org+'-'+o.OrgSUB as 'orgsub',o.org,count(g.id) as caseNo,
     grouping(o.Org+'-'+o.OrgSUB ) AS ORGSUBTOTAL, grouping(o.org) AS orgTOTAL 
     from g,o
            where  g.ORG+'-'+g.ORGSUB = o.ORG+'-'+o.ORGSUB and o.active='y' and 
      GROUP BY o.Org+'-'+o.OrgSUB ,o.Org
      WITH ROLLUP ORDER BY o.Org+'-'+o.OrgSUB desc, o.Org desc, ORGSUBTOTAL , OrgTOTAL
```

if i change   `GROUP BY o.Org+'-'+o.OrgSUB ,o.Org` to   `GROUP BY o.Org+'-'+o.OrgSUB ,o.Org, o.OrgSub` the error goes away, but i am stuck with an extra row, which i do not need to see.

Answer (score 0):

I did not changed much. I would do this:

```
SELECT o.Org+'-'+o.OrgSUB as orgsub
     , o.PSO
     , count(g.id) as caseNo
     , grouping(o.Org+'-'+o.OrgSUB ) AS ORGSUBTOTAL
     , grouping(o.PSO) AS PSOTOTAL 
FROM  g JOIN o
ON  (g.ORG = o.ORG) 
AND (g.ORGSUB = o.ORGSUB)
WHERE o.active='y' 
GROUP BY orgsub, o.PSO 
WITH ROLLUP 
ORDER BY orgsub desc, o.PSO desc, ORGSUBTOTAL , PSOTOTAL
```

I dont know why you did this: `o.Org+'-'+o.OrgSUB as 'orgsub'` I changed it to `o.Org+'-'+o.OrgSUB as orgsub`. I would liked to test it, but I hope it does work.

Comment: the o.PSO works i changed your query to the org and orgsub combination and it did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that its taking offence at the repeated presence of o.org in your group by query. To simplify things (and make it easier to read), could you create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW orgSubView AS 
   SELECT o.Org+'-'+o.OrgSUB as orgsub, o.org as org, o.PSO as pso, g.id as caseNo 
   FROM g,o 
   WHERE g.ORG+'-'+g.ORGSUB = o.ORG+'-'+o.ORGSUB and o.active='y'
```

(or pull this query into a new table..) and then run your group by query against this:

```
SELECT orgsub, pso ,count(caseNo)
FROM orgSubView 
GROUP BY orgsub ,pso
```

or

```
GROUP BY orgsub, org
```

Then add your extra bits (rollups and groupings) if that works..